# Java - SQL процедура

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java, sql

Привет всем. Необходимо получить ResultSet из такой процедуры:

```
exec ais_disp.p_lk.p_add_client
(v_sis_id     => 1640,
 v_proc_id    => 1,
 v_time_start => to_date('01032013 00:00','ddmmyyyy hh24:mi'),
 v_time_end   => to_date('31032013 23:59','ddmmyyyy hh24:mi'));
select * from ais_disp.v_lk_1;
commit;
```

Как это запихнуть в java код? Пробовал через `CallableStatement`, но туда не получается всунуть select из процедуры.

Comment: что за база данных?

Comment: Oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResultSet можно получить многими способами, фактически вы можете вернуть массив определенного типа, который будет содержать ваши результаты, можете использовать `pipe` функции pl/sql, можете вернуть курсор из функции и получить строки от туда.

в данном конкретном случае можно попробовать анонимный блок и подстановочную переменную, хотя я так ни разу не делал :)

java code:

```
...
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("
begin
    ais_disp.p_lk.p_add_client
(v_sis_id     => 1640,
 v_proc_id    => 1,
 v_time_start => to_date('01032013 00:00','ddmmyyyy hh24:mi'),
 v_time_end   => to_date('31032013 23:59','ddmmyyyy hh24:mi'));
commit;
open :my_cursor for select * from ais_disp.v_lk_1;
end;
");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cs.execute();
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);
...
```

Если так не выйдет то придется делать собственную функцию и уже оттуда возвращать курсор

```
create or replace function test(data_in var) return sys_refcursor is
   ret_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin
   open ret_cursor for select * from ...;
   return ret_cursor;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас по сути 2 запроса:

первый надо выпонить как `CallableStatement`, а второй как вызов raw sql через `Statement.execute()`